# Specifying Moxy runtime for Play project with model in dependency

Tags: java, playframework, jaxb, sbt, moxy

I'm working on a Play Framework project (WebProject) where I am using a jaxb/Moxy model defined in a jar I am importing through SBT. This jar is created from another project (ModelProject) by adding a "jaxb.properties" file to the package containing the model classes:
`javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`

To get this working for the unit tests in the ModelProject I had to add the following line to the build.sbt file:
`resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory { _ / "src" }`

My question is: Is there a way that I can use the Moxy runtime when I create a JAXBContext in the WebProject, using a class from the ModelProject to bootstrap it? Ideally I'd like to specify this within the ModelProject as it will be used by other projects in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not an ideal solution but I just decided to create a package in the WebProject containing a "MoxyBootstrapper" class and a jaxb.properties file containing the `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory` line.

I then pass this class in when creating a new instance of the JAXBContext.